# What is equivalent to "!((x > y) && (y <= 0))"

Tags: if-statement

What is the equivalent to the condition:

```
!((x > y) && (y <= 0))
```

Is it:

```
!(x > y) && !(y <= 0)

(x <= y) || (y > 0) 

(x < y) || (y > 0)
```

After initializing the variables to make them into y = -3 and x = -3 I was able to isolate only the second one to display the same results as the first. Does this mean that this is the only one equivalent to it?

How exactly do you use truth tables or the "De Morgan's Law"?

Comment: See De Morgan's Law. Also note the relation between `x>y` and `!(x<=y)` (I don't know what Law this is). After simplification, use a Truth Table to validate the selection.

Comment: Which one do you think it is? Show your efforts instead of just dumping your homework. Do you know De Morgan's laws? Truth tables etc?

Comment: I believe it is the second one and I did not just dump my homework. I just wanted to obtain a second opinion so I would know if I was doing this problem correctly... This is my first time posting on stack overflow and I did not want to fill the post with unnecessary background info. Thanks for the feedback though. @CoolGuy

Comment: @JerryBarns If so, then please show your efforts. Your question as it currently stands, looks like a homework dump. Edit your question to include the new information. Also read topics in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to know how to ask, what all you can ask here etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its the second one : (x <= y) || (y>0)

Comment: Are you able to elaborate why you believe this? I was testing it by inputting the info into if statements and I got two as well. I'm just not fully sure why this occurs after playing with the integers for a while.